# Carpet cleaning types, vapor vs hot water vacuum

Tags: carpet, vacuum

I have an around five year old carpet. It has accumulated some dust. A pet sometimes does a wee, that I collect with paper tissues, but of course not completely. My dust and hair stays also. Just vacuuming is not perfect. I would like to clean it more properly.

I have found there are two types of vacuums:

1 - steam / vapor vacuum, no chemicals, reportedly less than five min carpet drying time https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_steam_cleaner

2 - classic Carpet extractors, available in a local store for hire, require a bucket of water and a chemical at input, carpet reportedly takes 4 to 24 hours to dry

How effective are these two methods for the stated purpose? Not looking for specific brand but rather for a general note on suitability of these methods.

It is a berber carpet. It is built in, so putting it in the washer or shower isn't an option.

Thanks.

Comment: The internet is filled with product comparison/review sites. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this, however, is not one of them.

Comment: @FreeMan when searching, they seem vague  , most misuse the term 'steam cleaning to mean the bucket and chemicals. I have found it exceedingly difficult to collect any information about the vapor type vacuum

Comment: We just use soap and water , then scrub and suck water up with upright carpet cleaner. Fans dry it fairly fast. Pretty much the same as the commercial carpet cleaners we have hired.

Comment: You might need both, though with a berber you need to make sure it's short enough that the 'Vax' type cleaner won't wreck the pile. [Vax is dry to walk in an hour, completely dry in a day] Steamers will loosen dirt, but doesn't really remove it beyond what wipes off with the cloth [best for hard surfaces], unless you actually blow it out with the high pressure nozzle, which just moves it elsewhere in the room. [I'll flesh this into an actual answer if re-opened]

Comment: The 'classic' ones actually work, if they have an agitator. I'd assume a steam / vapor vacuum that actually works is like $5k. But I have no idea, because I'm not into newfangled, +1. There's only two possible answers: These new ones are shit. Or, I've used both and am never going back to the other. - This is not a PR; It's what type of tool actually cleans carpet. - a PR is that it should say Hoover on it.

Comment: At some point, even though a carpet may be completely, 100 percent clean, it will still look dirty in sections because of wear patterns.  The nylon fibers get micro fractures and the carpet will not reflect light like the non-worn portions do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be thorough, you need both.

Steam cleaners are good for hard floors. On carpet they will sterilise to some extent, but they have no mechanism to lift the dirt except for a cloth wrapped round the steam delivery area.
If you had a unit with separate boiler, hose & attachments, then you can use the direct steam jet to blast at particularly stubborn areas - note this will actually saturate the surface. Steam is only 'dry' when you don't use much of it. Once you're giving one small area a good blast, it's just as 'wet' as water [of course].
Blasting it like this will actually shift particulate matter & oils, but really all it does is blow them away to land elsewhere.

Once you've done your deep clean of the stubborn areas with the steamer, you then really need to go over the entire carpet with a wet/suction system.
This will lift a lot of the dirt pre-loosened by the steamer & a lot more besides.
The 'wet' cleaners achieve their version of sanitisation using chemicals rather than heat.

Note that in the UK, the best-known manufacturer of wet/suction cleaners offers a free steam mop cleaner like your example when you buy direct from them. [They've been running this offer for several years, I doubt they're going to stop any time soon]. If you buy it elsewhere - no free mop, separate £60 purchase.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work, +1. That's why I only take carpets *out*.